# How to find available timezones in a country using momentjs

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

I would like to retrieve a list of timezones with utc offsets from momentjs by country name. For example, I would like to have something like

```
   momentObject.getTimezones("America")
```

Which would return a list of timezones like

```
   ['UTC−11:00 (ST) — American Samoa, Jarvis Island, Kingman Reef, Midway Atoll, Palmyra Atoll',
    ....
```

Does functionality like this exist in the library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That functionality has been requested, and is pending in the following pull request:

https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/pull/410

However, it would accept a country code (such as `US`), and would return a list of time zone identifiers, such as `America/Los_Angeles`.  Note that the list you gave are not the values that would be returned.

Also keep in mind that one cannot assign a single offset to an entire time zone without considering point-in-time, so that would not be a part of the functionality either.  See "time zone != offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Comment: the feature has been merged 6 days ago : )  https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/getting-country-zones/

Comment: Finally. I asked this question a really long time ago.

Answer (score 3):

### moment-timezone

MomentJS offers a moment-timezone package:

`moment.tz.names();` would return an Array of all Timezones. These Timezones are prefixed with their respective continents; `America/Detroit`. You could easily filter this Array by Continent using plain JavaScript.

### countries-and-timezones

To get a country/timezone matching you would definitely need another package like [countries-and-timezones](https://github.com/manuelmhtr/countries-and-timezones) which offers a simple API to get Timezones by ISO country code:

```
countriesAndTimezones.getTimezonesForCountry('MX');
```

returns:

```
[ { name: 'America/Mexico_City',
    utcOffset: -360,
    offsetStr: '-06:00',
    countries: [ 'MX' ] },
  { name: 'America/Cancun',
    utcOffset: -300,
    offsetStr: '-05:00',
    countries: [ 'MX' ] },
  { name: 'America/Merida',
    utcOffset: -360,
    offsetStr: '-06:00',
    countries: [ 'MX' ] },
  { name: 'America/Monterrey',

...
```

Note, that there is an n x m relation between Countries and Timezones (hence a Timezone may live in multiple countries). Therefore this package also contains a `getCountriesForTimezone()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone looking on how to get timezone by country code in momentjs without waiting for https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/pull/410 to be merged, you can thankfully get the .json file from moment package and retrieve the country object containing timezones.

Take a look: https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/blob/develop/data/meta/latest.json
And this comment should be helpful too: https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/289#issuecomment-354585784