# how can I get a list of all countries together with their time using moment js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

```
 const timezone = moment.tz.names();
  const timezoneList = [];

  timezone.forEach((element) => {
    timezoneList.push({ label: element, value: element });
  });
```

At the moment I am just getting the list but I am trying to get also the local time of each country together.

Thank you very much

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45766638/how-to-find-available-timezones-in-a-country-using-momentjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest having a look at [countries-and-timezones](https://github.com/manuelmhtr/countries-and-timezones), this has a very convenient list of countries along with their timezones.

Once we have a country's list of timezones we can get the local time(s), using
[Date.toLocaleTimeString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString) allowing us to log local times for each country.

I've done this for the first 20 countries below:

```js
let countries = Object.values(ct.getAllCountries()).sort(({ name: a}, { name: b}) => a.localeCompare(b)).slice(0,20);
console.log('Country'.padEnd(20), 'Local Time(s):')

for(let country of countries) {
    console.log(country.name.padEnd(20), getLocaleTimes(country.timezones).join(", "))
}

function getLocaleTimes(timeZones) {
    return [...new Set(timeZones.map(getLocalTime))];
}

function getLocalTime(timeZone) {
    return new Date().toLocaleTimeString([], { timeZone, });
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/manuelmhtr/countries-and-timezones@latest/dist/index.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: That was super helpful than you very much :)

Comment: Glad to be of help!